# Google-analytics framework for predictive analysis

Tags: google-analytics, machine-learning, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the google-analytics framework to create predictive analysis tools. For example I would like to cluster my webpage visitors, etc.
In general, is there any list of machine learning algorithms implemented by this framework? for example: regression, clustering, classification, feature selection, etc.
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your language of choice, you might want to export your Google Analytics Metrics to flat files or a database and then start experimenting with ML models. Two popular languages with stable ML Implementations are Python and R. R's [caret](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/) package includes tools for building a predictive model pipeline. Python's [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) also contains implementations of all major classes of ML algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

When you say GA framework I'll assume you're referring to the set of Google Analytics APIs listed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/). The framework by itself doesn't provide machine learning capabilities. It merely provides access to the processed and aggregated GA data stored in Google's servers. You can use the API and feed the data to a machine learning application/system/program that does all of the stuff you mentioned.